# syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in php recordset

Tags: php, syntax-error, recordset

I have error  :-

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in php record set 
>    in

```
$query_Recordset2 = "SELECT stu_ID,stu_name, GROUP_CONCAT(if(class_no="lec_1", `attstatus`, NULL)) AS 'Lecturer 1', GROUP_CONCAT(if(class_no="lec_2", `attstatus`, NULL)) AS 'Lecturer 2' FROM attendance WHERE session_ID="1" GROUP BY stu_ID,stu_name";
```

There free syntax error  during testing at dreamweaver but when open the php file in browser pop out this error.Any solution to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure everything that shall be closed with semi-colons, actually is closed.?

Comment: try the "lec_2" to 'lec_2'

Comment: how is it possible I can see many concatenating string errors why your dreamweaver is not responding to them

Comment: @NarendraSisodia he mentioned it in his question, read it again.

Comment: What about **where session_ID**

Comment: $query_Recordset2 = "SELECT stu_ID,stu_name, GROUP_CONCAT(if(class_no="lec_1", `attstatus`, NULL)) AS 'Lecturer 1', GROUP_CONCAT(if(class_no="lec_2", `attstatus`, NULL)) AS 'Lecturer 2' FROM attendance WHERE session_ID="1"  GROUP BY stu_ID,stu_name";

Answer (score 0):

Replace your string with this

```
$query_Recordset2 = "SELECT stu_ID,stu_name, GROUP_CONCAT(if(class_no='lec_1', attstatus, NULL)) AS 'Lecturer 1', GROUP_CONCAT(if(class_no='lec_2', attstatus, NULL)) AS 'Lecturer 2' FROM attendance WHERE session_ID GROUP BY stu_ID,stu_name";
```

Comment: still does not work even changed from  "lec_2" to 'lec_2' and have syntax error in dreamweaver

Comment: This was only for your php error you specified in question, There are mysql error as well in query. if you can provide little info what exactly you are trying. I can provide with the right one

Comment: finally solve it..thanks for provide right code